# CSV Import with Python - Why brackets?

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing a script that will import a list of urls from a CSV, then loop through the URLs for a response.  When I import the CSV, each site is enclosed in brackets and single-quotes.

My csv looks like this:

```
http://cnn.com
http://yahoo.com
http://google.com
```

The name of the csv is `sites.csv`.

Here is the code I'm running:

```
import csv

datafile = open('path/to/file/sites.csv', 'rU')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile)
for row in datareader:
    print row
```

Here is the output:

```
['http://cnn.com']
['http://yahoo.com']
['http://google.com']
```

Is there a way to not include the `['`,`']` around the URL when reading the CSV?  If there is not, then is my solution to strip out the `['`,`']` in my loop, then access the URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each row consists of a python *list* of columns, with only one column in this case.

Since there *are* no comma-separated columns, just one item per line, you don't need to use the `csv` module here. Just read from the file directly:

```
with open('path/to/file/sites.csv', 'rU') as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        print line.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a row object, so try like this...

```
print row[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

how bout just

```
print map(str.strip,open('path/to/file/sites.csv', 'rU'))
```

afaik the open file handle will get garbage collected next time it collects garbage as it will have no references